# naniar creating extra plot in rmarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, missing-data, naniar

I am using the package naniar and it is producing an extra plot. I have read the documentation and could not figure out why this empty plot is appearing. Is there a way to remove it but still keep the second figure and say the second and third if that existed?

[image]

```
library(naniar)

# create data 
data0 <- data.frame("A" = c(NA,NA,1,1), "B"= c(1,NA,1,1),"C"= c("john","john",NA,NA),"D"= c("john","john","john","john"))

# Naniar plot
nval <- naniar::n_case_miss(data0) 
naniar::gg_miss_upset(data0,nsets=nval)
```

Comment: Do you get this in the knitted file (pdf or html).  I can't reproduce those in the output though it is just when you run by chunk

Comment: I get this if I run the chunk so it is wrapped in ``` {r}    ```

Comment: It is from the `UpSetR::upset()` being called

Comment: This in a rmd file, I get it if I run the chunk but also if I preview it, this shows in html form

Comment: @akrun , thank you. How would I fix this? I thought that the ```naniar::``` is explicitly calling ```naniar``` ?

Comment: When I run it, I couldn't find the empty plot on pdf or html.  IT only appeared on the chunk run

Comment: if you check the source code, it calls `Create_matrix`, `Create_layout` etc

Comment: That is strange, it is definitely showing for me. It just shows as a large empty area.

Comment: Maybe it is related to your package version

Comment: I used `packageVersion("naniar")
[1] ‘0.6.1’`

Comment: @akrun, same here

Comment: What about the version of rmarkdown package

Comment: ```packageVersion("rmarkdown")[1]
[1] ‘2.8’```

Comment: that is also same for me.  I did the knitting with `Rstudio 1.4.1106` and on R 4.1.0

Comment: I am using the same rstudio but r ```R version 4.0.5```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about the behavior

Comment: Yeah it is strange, thanks for all the help though akrun, I am sure someone else will run into the same issue eventually. If I manage to trouble shoot it, I will post what worked.

Comment: Do you get the empty plot when you knit the file?

Comment: For me the 'problem' also only exist when running just this chunk (in the preview window). When I knit / execute the whole .Rmd file to either .pdf or html (as you anyway do once your document is finished), no empty plot can be seen any more. It would help, if you show us an example of your knitted html or pdf with the empty figure (not just the preview).